# Установка приложения на ПК

Tags: c#, visual-studio, установка

Создал приложение в VS, протестил его и осталось только сделать так, чтобы его можно было устанавливать на ПК
Как это сделать?
Если ещё проще:
У всех приложений есть установочный файл, его нажимаешь и приложение устанавливается на ПК.
Мне нужно либо что то такое, либо просто перенести некий файл, хранящий мое приложение и запускающий его на других ПК

Comment: клацаешь правой кнопкой мыши на солюшне в Солюшн Эксплоурере. Там лезешь в пропертиз. И где-то там был экспорт в стандартный инсталлер. Но где не подскажу т.к. давно открывал вижуалку. Это самый простой способ. А если хочется самому создать инсталлер кастомный - то в интернете море туториалов по ключевику "Visual Studio create/export installer"

Comment: Зависит очень сильно от целей и самого проекта, вообще, вопрос очень обширный, нужна конкретика.  Допустим у нас простой мини проект, который нужно просто запустить - какие там зависимости есть? .dll? База? Картинки и др. файлы? Предположим у нас просто набор .dll, ок, мы можем их склеить в один .exe? Можем. В итоге получим один .exe файл, который запустится везде без проблем. Нужна установка? Не думаю. Картинки и др. файлы - мы можем из закинуть в ресурсы .exe? Если да, то опять нам не нужна установка. База - какая? Может это SQLite, который мы можем создать при первом запуске?

Comment: Установка нужна тогда, когда у вас есть много зависимостей и много нужно сделать автоматических действий для того, чтобы ваше приложение успешно работало на машине клиента (установить базу, скачать с интернета что либо, распаковать, записать в реестр, и прочее прочее прочее), во всех остальных случаях, установка, это захламление машины клиента, не более. И даже тогда, когда вам нужна установка, выбор того, через что устанавливать опять же, зависит от целей, ибо есть куча конструкторов установщика, можете даже написать свой, который будет прописывать себя в нужные места. Так что думайте.

Comment: Я сделал проект на своей машине в vs, мне нужно чтобы он работал на другой машине.
К проекту подключен .net connector для работы с бд на хостинге и эксель интероп

Comment: Чего вы тогда собрались устанавливать? `.net connector` - если не ошибаюсь, набор библиотек (.dll). который должен просто идти вместе с проектом. `эксель интероп` - это тоже .dll, которая должна быть в проекте (кстати для нее обязательно на компе должен быть установлен сам эксель). В итоге весь ваш проект состоит из набора библиотек, которые можно объединить в один `.exe` и вот у вас уже утилита, а не приложение, ну или без внедрения, положить их около .exe и тогда достаточно просто распаковать. Уверены, что нужен установщик? Я вам сейчас лишь говорю, чтоб вы проанализировали свой проект.

Comment: Я видимо при постановке вопроса не учел, что не знаю разницы между утилитой и приложением.
Сейчас попробовал просто перенести папку с проектом на другую машину и возникло исключение при запуске exe, думаю это из за отсутствия экселя
Но в любом случае спасибо)